# Only 1 of 8 nodes is responding in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We run an App Service at Azure that is configured with 8 nodes. After the latest restart of the application, only 1 node is responding. We can judge that looking at live stream data in Application Insights. Requests from the clients mostly fail because they are directed to the dead nodes.

We run Windows environment with Java and Tomcat.

Any idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a vague request guys. That was kind of emergency. Anyway, the problem is resolved, and I hope this information can be useful for someone getting into same kind of trouble.

The problem appeared to be with Azure infrastructure that experienced some failure and switched to a failover storage resource. Our application could not be started after that. Advised by the Microsoft's support, we downgraded our service plan, and then upgraded it again, thus causing all nodes be created from scratch. That helped.

Comment: Just a heads-up, you could review 
The ‘Service Health’ - Service issues view shows any ongoing problems in Azure services that are impacting your resources. You can understand when the issue began, and what services and regions are impacted. You can also read the most recent update to understand what Azure is doing to resolve the issue. 
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview